# Контекстное меню DataGrid. Получить значение

Tags: c#, wpf

Решил уйти с winform и сразу же упёрся в проблему.

DataGrid'у добавил контекстное меню и не могу никак получить значение ячейки строки, в которой это меню было вызвано.

В winform'ах я делал так:

```
        var point = dataGridView1.PointToClient(contextMenuStrip1.Bounds.Location);
        var info = dataGridView1.HitTest(point.X, point.Y);
        string reader = dataGridView1[0, info.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
```

В WPF что-то не могу понять как это сделать.

Контекстное меню в дизайнере:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="DataDevices" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="285" Width="270">
        <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Звуковой сигнал" Click="Sound" />
                <MenuItem Header="Сигнал светодиода" Click="Blink" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Покажите как добавили меню

Comment: @Андрей добавил код

Comment: Так вы добавили контекстное меню к DataGrid, а не к его строкам

Comment: @Андрей, Наверное :) Ведь контекстное меню выскакивает у меня при клике в любом месте DataGrid. А как тогда указать на конкретные строки?

Comment: В DataGrid... походу через стиль строки, DataGrid в этом плане нетривиален... Попробую набросать ответ как это должно делаться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я расскажу как делать через команды.

Добавьте себе такой класс:

```
class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    protected readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    protected readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, _ => true) { }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
        _canExecute = canExecute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(canExecute));
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute(parameter);

    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        => CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Он представляет собой простую реализацию команды WPF.

Теперь для каждого пункта меню заведите команду, например:

```
public ICommand BeepCommand { get; }
```

В конструкторе VM (если вы используете MVVM) или своего окна создаете команду:

```
BeepCommand = new DelegateCommand(o => Beep((Item)o));
```

Здесь `Item` - это тип ваших элементов, которые вы выводите в `DataGrid`, далее сам метод, который будет вызываться по команде:

```
void Beep(Item item)
{
    ...
}
```

Также, если вы не используете подход MVVM, задайте окну контекст в конструкторе, например:

```
DataContext = this;
```

Теперь в разметке, добавим меню в ресурсы:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="conMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Звуковой сигнал"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Сигнал светодиода"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.Resources>
```

разметка `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{DynamicResource conMenu}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Теперь контекстное меню привязано к конкретной строке грида.

Привяжем теперь команды к пунктам меню.

Так как пункт меню помещен в `DataGrid` (который является `ItemsControl`'ом), то контекстом этого пункта является сам элемент, поэтому мы его легко можем передать в параметре `CommandParameter="{Binding}"`, но сама команда определена в контексте окна, поэтому к ней придется идти через `RelativeSource FindAncestor`, в итоге получается вот что:

```
<MenuItem Header="Звуковой сигнал"
          Command="{Binding DataContext.BeepCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
          CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

Всё, аналогично для остальных команд.

Comment: Ну в целом концепцию понял. Добавил всё что Вы написали в код, но класс весь ошибками покрылся. Ругается на `_execute`, пишет что неоднозначность между `_execute` и `_execute(parameter)`. Затем `=> _canExecute(parameter)` пишет что `=>`требуется ";", `_canExecute(parameter)` пишет что метод должен возвращать тип и т.д.

Comment: Эмм, @Николай, у вас студия какая?

Comment: версия: 12. Разве версия студии может на это повлиять? Версию фрейморка пробовал разную выставлять.

Comment: Конечно может, у вас версия C# старая

Comment: Под C# 5.0 должно скомпилироваться такое: https://pastebin.com/YBZwzZRY Но я вам всё же рекомендую поставить свежую версию студии (2017)

Comment: Да, класс заработал. `public ICommand BeepCommand { get; }` а где эта команда должна находится? И метод `void Beep(Item item)` в какой момент вызывается? С MVVM я вижу это, но я его не использую.

Comment: @Николай, А где ваша коллекция, которую вы в DataGrid выводите, находится?

Comment: Первый метод опрашивает оборудование и в `DataTable` пишет, а второй делает `DataDevices.ItemsSource = data.DefaultView;`, где DataDevices - DataGrid,а data - DataTable.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65517/discussion-between--and-).